# Suspend idle AWS instance automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, suspend

I have to set up an AWS instance for a web application that is being used sporadically, a few hours at a time, a few times per month. The application requires a sizeable instance in terms of virtual cpus and memory, so keeping it running 24/7 would run up a steep bill, and since the time it is being used is below ~5% I am looking for a way to automatically suspend the instance if CPU utilization drops below 10% for >2 hours (for example). Also, ideally (but not strictly required) a request to the application's URL would start the instance if it is suspended.

1. My first idea is to set up CloudWatch to record any requests to the URL, as well as the instance's CPU utilization. A Lambda function then periodically checks if the last request was over 2h ago and CPU utilization has been low for that time as well; if true then suspend the instance.
2. The starting of the instance could be done by having a special "wakeup" URL (separate from the app's URL) which triggers a lambda function to wake the instance if asleep.

Is there a recommended or more standard way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a script running on the instance that continually measures "usage". (The actual definition of this is up to you — it might be based on app usage, or CPU, or however you want to define it.)

Once the script determines that the instance is not being used, is can simply issue an **operating system Shutdown command**. If the instance `Shutdown Behavior = Stop`, then the instance will gracefully shutdown and stop.

You could then use your 'wake-up' process to **Start** the instance again.

Comment: That is indeed an idea, although the wake-up process would be longer with this option.

Answer (score 0):

You can create auto scale group that starting with 1 instance behind Elastic LB. When there is a load with given parameter ( such as cpu load, ram usage , network traffic etc ), the new instance automatically created. When the load is down, it will close the instance automatically too. There is no need to use lambda ;)

Comment: My minimum number is 0 instances, and my maximum number is 1 instance. Would an auto scale group work for that?

Comment: Yes, setting group minimal capacity to 0 is enough for this. You need dynamic scaling https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html

Comment: @nickolay.laptev  very interesting! The added trickiness is that the instance is stateful (i.e. the database is in the same instance). Can I tell autoscaling to stop/start the same instance rather than create a new copy?

Comment: Not like this (scale in leads to termination always, not stopping https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroupLifecycle.html), the only thing we can tell it is to forbid scaling in (terminating) some instance. It's not bad because having DB in the same instance is not good anyway. But you can use the same EBS snapshot (as a base volume) for new instance. So new instance will have the same state as the old one - please note that you need to keep EBS snapshot up to date in this case.

Comment: The database should not be located in autoscale group because multiple mysql without clustering cause data loss. The data base layer should be distinct. The autoscale instance member must handle api load, also the backend must support token based auth ( or session with redis ) If client upload sth like jpg, video etc, then the s3 bucket can be used or the lambda function can move it to another ftp, cdn etc